Request for Suggestions on Evaluating a Finite Sum
Let us define the following function, which depends on  $n$ and $q$:
\begin{equation}
f(n;q) = \sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^{\ell} (2n-\ell-1)! \, \ell^q}{\ell!\, (n-\ell)!\, (n-\ell-1)!}, \quad \text{where} \quad q = 0, 1, 2, \dots
\end{equation}
For fixed values of $q$, it is possible to evaluate the finite sum over $\ell$ on a case-by-case basis. For example, I found:
\begin{align}
f(n;0) &= 1, \\
f(n;1) &= n - n^2, \\
f(n;2) &= \frac{1}{2} \left(n^4 - 4n^3 + 3n^2\right).
\end{align}
Could someone suggest a strategy to evaluate the sum over $\ell$ for arbitrary $q$? In other words, is there a way to determine a closed-form expression for $f(n;q)$?
Any comments or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

You might want to look at differences like $f(n; q+1) - f(n, q)$. It also appears (from the three examples) that you have $f(n ; q) = n^q (p_q(n, q))$, where $p_q$ is a polynomial of degree $q$. You might try to find subsequent $p_q$'s by assuming this form and then seeing what the value of $p_q(n) - p_q(n-1)$ tells you abut the coefficients (when you evaluate for some particular values of $n$).

You might get a combinatorial interpretation by rewriting the four factorials as the multinomial coefficient $\binom{2n-\ell-1}{\ell,n-1,n-\ell-1}$.
